# ViewPager onPageSelected function is fired before layout is initialized

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard

I need to focus to first `EditText` when I switch page in my `ViewPager`. I made `onPageChangeListener` which will call requestFocus function for specific page. For this screen it should requestFocus for first `EditText`.

What I found out: function called in `instantiateItem()` inside `PagerAdapter` is called after `onPageSelected`. This is logically correct and I should call `requestFocus()` when my custom 'onCreate' function (when layout is added to `ViewGroup`) is called.

But this is causing serious issues when more than 1 page is inside `ViewPager`.

If you select specific page (for example `tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.select()`) it will call this custom `onCreate` not only for selected page, but sometimes also next page. That means I will call two requestFocus functions on 2 pages (even if second one is not visible and should not be instantiate).

I made this solution (I called requestFocus when you select page). But this will cause problem. If you switch to last page for example at start, it will call this request function before layout is passed to `ViewGroup` of `PagerAdapter`.
This makes function call useless, because `firstEt` is not initialized yet. (null)

Any solution to this?

PagerAdapter:

```
override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): View {
        val layout = pageList[position].onCreate(container)
        container.addView(layout)
        return layout
    }
```

Screen3:
Inside onCreate:

```
firstEt?.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        log("KeyboardVisible: onFocusChange $hasFocus")
}
```

Function inside Screen3 object:

```
fun requestInitFocus(){
        log("KeyboardVisible: requestingFocus")
        firstEt?.requestFocus()
        app.showKeyboard()
}
```

In Activity:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                when(pageList[position]){
                    is Screen3 -> {
                        (pageList[position] as Screen3).apply {
                            requestInitFocus()
                        }
                    }
                     ...
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add logic to capture focus in the fragment instead of the adapter

fragment_3_layout.xml

```
...
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             <requestFocus/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
```

Screen3.kt

```
...
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        requireActivity().showKeyboard(passwordEditText)
    }
```

ActivityExtensions.kt

```
fun Activity.showKeyboard(view: View): Boolean? =
   inputMethodManager?.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
```

Comment: Its not fragment what Im using. its just custom Object. I dont want to use Fragments in Android apps ... ever :) onCreate function is just abstract function of parent Object returning View (which is layout inflated in page)